# How do I make this question on-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I wanted to ask a question about the impact of the **Government's intervention in surge pricing**.

However, I am not sure whether this question would be marked as too broad or not.

I wanted to know how the ban on surge pricing (in Delhi, India) would affect the taxi aggregator companies, the consumers and the economy.

So, how do I frame the question to make it on-topic in this site. Is this okay?

**How does the ban on surge pricing affect the companies, customers and the economy?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to ask the question. One of two things will happen:

1. The question will be fine.
2. People will vote to close the question and post a comment explaining why. If this happens then you can edit the question and then it will be reopened.

Comment: Thank You. I have asked the [question](http://economics.stackexchange.com/q/11671/5642).  Pl feel free to edit the tags (I wasn't completely sure with them). :)